# How do I create a Binary Search Tree from a General tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

As the title states.  I am trying to create a binary search tree from a general tree that I have created.  The code for my general node class is:

```
Node<E> parent;
E data;
ArrayList<Node<E>> children = new ArrayList<Node<E>>();

public Node(E data){
    this.data = data;
}

public ArrayList<Node<E>> getChildren(){
    return this.children;
}

public void addChild(Node child){
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
        if (child.toString().equals(children.get(i).toString())){
            System.out.println("already exists");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter > 0){}
    else{   
        children.add(child);
    }

}

public void removeChild(Node<E> child){
    children.remove(child);
}

public Node<E> getChild(Node<E> child){
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
        if (children.get(i) == child){
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void setParent(Node parent){
    this.parent = parent;
}

public Node<E> getParent(){
    return this.parent;
}

public boolean isDirectory(Node node){
    if (data == node.data){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean hasChildren(){
    return getChildren() != null;
}

public E getData(){
    return this.data;
}

public String toString(){
    return data.toString();
}
}//end class
```

And my tree class is full of methods to the brim, so to save all you guys the eye strain, my tree class consists of a root and the constructor which sets the root as the root of the tree.  I know that to convert the general tree to the binary search tree, i must set my general tree root to the root of the binary search tree.  My question is then where do i go from there?  How do i traverse my general tree to add the nodes to the binary search tree?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just keep dividing every non-binary tree node into a binary node (every two consecutively ordered children can be replaced with a binary node child with a single child), until it cannot / should not be divide (as it is a binary node) - a BST does not need be balanced per definition, although other restrictions may be applied per the task. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree for various ways of perform rotations if the tree needs to be balanced at the end.

Comment: In a binary search tree, you need something that is stored (e.g.: data) and a search key to build the tree-order on. What is your key here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to convert from a general tree to binary SEARCH tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086958/is-there-a-way-to-convert-from-a-general-tree-to-binary-search-tree)

Answer (score 0):

A general tree is not **binary** because it may have arbitrary number of child nodes and is not **search** because its nodes do not have any specific order. As a consequence constructing a binary search tree from a general tree is just the same as inserting all the nodes of the general tree in the binary search tree. Please note I would not call this **convert** it is more **constructing** a binary search tree from the nodes in a general tree.

Comment: How would i go about inserting all the nodes into a binary tree then? @Ivaylo Strandjev