# How to create a general tree with basic function like insert in java

Tags: java, tree

//I have some basic code written down for the General Tree.

```
class GeneralTree {
     public static class Node{
         String data;
         ArrayList<Node> link;
         Node(){}
         public void setValue(String data){
            this.data = data;
        }

         public String getValue(){
            return data;
        }
     }
     Node root;
     int degree;
     String type; //shows tree type;

     public GeneralTree(){
         degree = 0;
         root = null;
         type = "";
     }
     public GeneralTree(Node root, int degree){
          this.root = root;
          this.degree = degree;
     }
     public Node getRoot(){return root;}
 }


 public class Hw5 {
 }
```

I tried searching the internet for explanation on General trees. I understand how they work on paper and can even convert a general tree to Binary on paper, but I do not know how a general tree code implementation will work. Binary tree has right and left childs, they are easy to deal with. on the other hand, general trees have an ArrayList that stores multiple childs, which is the confusing part for me. i do not know how an insert function will look like for this and how I will even traverse this tree.

Need Help With:

1. Code implementation for general tree.
2. How an insert function will work for the general tree
3. if you can direct me to some reading material, that would be amazing too.

Comment: I can traverse, search, insert, delete in Binary Trees, but General trees are more complicated.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086958/is-there-a-way-to-convert-from-a-general-tree-to-binary-search-tree)  
i have read this already. Their code has some parts i am looking for, but does not show an insert function or how it will look like in the main function.

Comment: [link](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS3/html/GenTreeIntro.html)I found the General tree traversal. Still confused on how values will be inserted and how that structure will look like in a general tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that by looking for the solution by myself I learn much more and it sticks better. I'm not saying that you should do that too, Googling skills are your best way to find what you need faster because when you are a novice you can't put what you are looking for in words (I speak from experience).

Use Github, stackoverflow and Tabnine to find code samples, there are plenty out there (use keywords "general tree java code example"). Have a look at a few examples and try to read the code and understand what is happening. You can run the code in debug mode, put some break points in and step through the execution to see what happens. Debugging is a very useful skill.

You can find some examples of general trees here:

https://github.com/cmilliga/GeneralTreesCollegeWork

https://github.com/Faisal-AlDhuwayhi/Electric-Power-Grid/tree/master/Project-Code/src

Each node can have children Node(s) so the ArrayList is there to keep track of the children for that Node. If you want to add a new Node you need to iterate through the Node and its children.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I did not even think of searching GitHub. Thankyou.

Comment: No problem. I hope you found what you're looking for.